# MahApps.Metro DatePicker: cuts off the date

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, mahapps.metro

I have updated my application from/to following versions:

- MahApps.Metro: 0.11.0.31-ALPHA (net40) --> 1.4.3 (net45)
- MahApps.Metro.Resources: 0.1.0.1 (net40) --> 0.6.1.0 (net45)

Now the DatePicker is shown differently:

[image]

Is there a way to show it as before (shrink the icon, etc.)?

**Edit:**
After the hint from punker76 it looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvvnk.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width and height of the inner icon with this attached property

```
Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonWidth="22"
```

`22` is the default value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, punker76! It's better, but not the solution, yet. There's a wide space between text and button...

Comment: @liju1970 You're right, I saw this too. Will fix this in next release.